# Problem with .htaccess and index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

In my development server the, the referrer name will look like `dev.host.in` and the ip will look like `123.456.456.111/dev/`

I am using codeigniter framework. I have already set the `.htaccess` file to remove the `index.php`. When I'm accessing site through `dev.host.in/testproject/` its working fine. But when I'm accessing it with `123.456.456.111/dev/testproject/` it doesn't display the page.
But when I access `123.456.456.111/dev/testproject/index.php` I am getting the site.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Care to post your htaccess "modification" ?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

If you're still having problems, visit this [link](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/).